# How to test a ReactiveForm containing <mat-checkbox>?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've trouble setting up `<mat-checkbox>` in a ReactiveForm and get **No value accessor for form control [...]** when testing.

When I run the app in dev mode it works as expected.

When using this:

```
<mat-checkbox
  id="allDay"
  type="checkbox"
  formControlName="allDay">
    <!-- i18n: @@event.allDay -->All Day Event?<!-- /i18n -->
</mat-checkbox>
```

I get this error when running `npm test`:

> Failed: No value accessor for form control with name: 'allDay'
>   Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'allDay'
>         at _throwError /node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js:1918:1)
>         at setUpControl /node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js:1828:1)
>         at FormGroupDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl
>   /node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js:4808:1)
>         at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName._setUpControl
>   /node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js:5396:1)
>         at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges
>   /node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js:5314:1)
>         at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline /node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10845:1)
>         at checkAndUpdateNodeInline /node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12349:1)
>         at checkAndUpdateNode /node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12288:1)
>         at debugCheckAndUpdateNode /node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:13149:22)
>         at debugCheckDirectivesFn /node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:13090:1)

But the code works for the other `<mat-form-field>`s without any problems:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    type="text"
    formControlName="name">
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there anything I must provide in my component Tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I forgot to add the Angular Material dependencies in my specs:

```
import { MatInputModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    EventFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule
  ],
  providers: [
    FormBuilder
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```